# Calling subscribe in subscribe, rxjs, angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know there are few other posts for calling subscribe inside subsribe, but I am not able to find a solution.

I am calling subscribe inside subscribe which I know it does not work correctly. The console.log prints **head** in random sequence. e.g. S1 has H1, S2 as H2, S3 as H3. The current program will print sometimes S1, S3, S2 and at other times S2, S3, S1.

The expectation is that the head of the state is printed sequentially. How can I achive it?

```
 GetStates(countryID).subscribe(
      data => {
           let states = JSON.parse(data);
            states.forEach(
             entry => {
               GetHeadOfState(entry.ID).subscribe(
                 head => {
                   console.log(head)
                 }
               )
             }
           ) 
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it but if the states you want are in fact an array you can first unpack the array (with `concatAll`/`mergeAll`) and then call `concatMap` on each state. The `concatMap` operator will run for each item and wait until it completes:

```
GetStates(countryID).pipe(
  map(data => JSON.parse(data)),
  concatAll(),
  concatMap(state => GetHeadOfState(state.ID)),
).subscribe(headOfState => ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mergeMap`/`mergeAll` operator here

```
getStatesAndCountry(countryID) {
    let states = GetStates(countryID);
    return states.pipe(
      mergeMap(map(state) => GetHeadOfState(state.ID))
    )
}

this.getStatesAndCountry(countryId).subscribe(
  value =>  console.log(val)
)
```

Comment: You can use mergeMap() to shorten it a bit https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor thanks for tip, updated the answer :)